# wrong Base64 string after bitmap photo encoding

Tags: android, base64

So in my app I have possibility to take photo. What I want to do later is to sent this photo to server using API as Base64 String. Here's my code to encode bitmap (photo) to String :

```
public static String convertPhotoToBase(Bitmap bmp) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        Log.e(TAG,  Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT));
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    }
```

Looks ok, right ? Well, it's not and I don't why String I'm receiving is not encoded correctly. I add, that bitmap is ok , cuz I can display it in ImageView without any problems.

String I'm getting looks like this :

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA8AAAAZACAIAAAA5PLyzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4                                                                                 nKS9WbbsOK4kagZ5DON9VM1/hncL9j7QEKTkHnFXKXOd8K2GBNETBEH+3//z/0mSBIgkAJpIfmhx                                                         kXQ6ABEkP/YPyPjT3SXe963b3f8AAEah28l2JYckwQUAEgDAyerDPtERZMpXZAJJGgyU7rjpDing                                              dNoN6MOrHrm7S4o/CUGEkbzOUQgASAYAzOHIQAl0wam8KGab8bKMOTrPjurpFfdv0d3piUwDAZiZ                                                               iGpTd6Oa/PCSvJvqITgpCaSMJEhelIEY8CDw6C7pdpMUQzPBkHBe5gAsxytZ9nvTScoR4FGQKCmo                                                     TF6QJbi4AVwSjLyAK6h2Xbgk6f5z9/u+izRXQEVSuqmFIuGW5EqwA/MkA2Y3q+HfNUCRvK5/mnYu                                                               Rl8ApCs+9gSYxEXyn4vVOxurt4Q7OeRPdyMZgNnVbGBmwcIBHoA73lxUXhc8byb+5YFgkkB2DVjw                                                           SQwnW7DgwIATja6ApAFz9x1RnowqgfkIAHiFdMxBNfxBkUSFw7nIAUBySqSasS8kQDfkUgwo+CpY                                                    SNVzoB3AxezLEBLBACbgUWmD6zLSsl8sWVBxQcjmuNT8jNIZJHF7DqEaiAZbHGgQSS65lgSwhm2B                                                            HKNCRtyB2wFXgJ56oWldVMOnaFrASe7+t4SXJE0AvJuZ4zn+7NbsCnCvfiFac/dbvPUXcCVDRnek                                                cAexqNTYAkI67lvufkPExeJb6SYpo5ldYEtfUIpwA80IY1BhYF7N82ZG0eFDU7EUvkkKmU0FEgMp                                             ziRDEyddcBkAlabNd6TQGChKNRikaPrQUoBC9LCUcH7lLdfWOpbkFBlJPiQl+cQulFZv6RZu3k0U                                    Ns8DUMqjk3SaJDrlvHFHd4HnhEHm/pc6xKLrYiTQiRjLJpv3zTAqpJldDHpJtB6vF3XMLAYYCmS9                             4D5GasXXYXFLJ6ScJtluCIAJ7n/5CO5I/AX/NPMAoPy+b5VddpYpvMDCbRtcAGEH2y5Ykdvdm16t                        jUmCaiBjGAFhaGkBTps8IBSDDREDYIbgydaioWAvWmtU+TIZf75ssaXBu8wsrMzUA+6uxpVuEYZg                      9c91Xdd1NRJaEABY+A9OAByOxIeLb1FWA8DfUng3eSX7kYYLmHojuFt/f/dkp2QSo7bGqWJppl71                   Qlq6ZzJ9zHrIN25JYewbvSruAgrJZcRQvocDzaIxqMBqC3Jf8VC6LX8o2knpS75lO2kXCTjC/AYm                        PHw52TS71LQRFo4Kgwop4ICFQ1Q8ORX+HXwkwK40YQA+jd/xQ4f2V5kvfL8mV812UjTzbru/Nahh                       M1CMMNtZREpueDFCO/DVVPgxo4v8wUcT/TQtQZscvb24gfoNFdnVavMc1AHtt156yJK6yzkipZdT                 Qy5sE5xvdpvh0EiivbwQjn613H0FyzoUvk9r+qG1dsBehyMc7PF4YW/neKW77Heax5BsgPrBV1bJ                  r8ANY/u/E4AHP69+yWSj7q65uTEWrzc7baAOlXeIwPz95O0fbHnAvP84u9jRiMIK8d72GniI8LPf              +Wfj9hhRdDK7Hkz+whLBz/NlSfx3JKw2AUypeXa0ydcE9U3P/L5z8E8rt9npE4AXNTtYvaYf/6J4                 J2KnBpvUZL+3/jNYS+/4nxx4wGxm7t5iOkkZN6KLbuG3cnj2++PNtl6v3DjR+K3T1y6auwa0B02/               jeDX6B6QbBpbO40wmKQh2VTEY8i/rwwKIC0DsbXW4aoe6SGh+d8mM7cLQHCO8BXVPy6WwWr9OZ++             km/awZfWgEmyXdy+cpSkerqmH9g1RtPCemY+X5u9Ezbm33MgU+JSZsHguvX0pwZeUlajPBTXYZEP                   +0Kc8njon8NAdGuLMysE0zAf3FgshcZ5M9MXzG/NVgsvWNik4MEE72rqiwUfNiLpvsO/XC+eBmtX            sMBnsFdxSc7/PuG8SwJNyonfYkoXBQgGenoOlGhNmPgBSIqgW053sgV7jrxRw5g4h2C+O81lkg2A            SBjprnbyqncCTn5kKaIOcbdVG1t7dNiOqcNbPAgYHQ6QdHoFFy1mSHM4y4HmYobF3Dy7ljb2Xdgo             +l1fzNiCPLssSlfwOy4P6Pch16D2RtrhMMGpmvAH1p4OdH29IaEavFBLB/H+q5JVYUM18e0nWCbz            xIzVBEARLym74t4xsLOjoanNDK2159usKb/mNKmoYCCFxNqwdmYW0Fo2tSY2TAPmm5RyhdZeELIr            wQZsjGJFTX5p3McViOp2LJvduHfpi/4K5CW2RxQeJwHgGq0d2uohYstMalhNnwLYnLZdnGOcn6MZ           oIkd4Yvo9uEZW+g+Fd8TgCmiQDCjAPiALUePXIWYMA2tiqFnjake3l3kiZAphk8zFs0bcMMeJPZU          uTq95O5xGYlF5YxmEmvZDQAZC4NXKM1EoREIBZ7mM9xVFy6LfgNlF1z6yYFNceCMXbQSASIMG4sA           BIx0gJTHOuaBdscNBZHTvhALSdGdcBPXQHi1sGPzoM5SyIE/WUTuAfPxYmsz8gIc8BB90SGAfhB0          aNUVZ0VJTUilgc35SzU1SIn2y8dEZYoYOnISvCoh+mUbKbF4piky9Iyj0AWg4m2BinSgmQHmTWem          fqt2WBFNnXJ0XkkmY6/WTqXx+vKkUb13ehEU9T7H6InEA3Xs8Pad6x6kke4e04855LVk3csm8GlZ          YLxoGe7vqxYCeqRpvy5AF8cqDW6v1yIY3J9IksnvJFb6+pbq8ZSs4nRtJHDHxTRgSSkp+Wc6jptz          Ep1V0waBcOIK1H2jmrrBGDgQkyVrDzDcPLuAe1lDV1PqpJ8gK8ewm53cZWzXLixsq8FigIyvE/wL          q7ccfQOhXFVuoTjVeGlCGBOSz9S2xSMhiwnbMueCJIcfk/FmrURRBzPI6Ck+H2q06XJinNUdx81y          hs+XzQaUMSpby1sJWwdiR9RlNrYUGbGixWdv52w4sPyuGI5mawqx3M7RYKL1Ie/9nsZkSxJOGFZf          /Ztt7vYgtPa5e+voQtTmITQFO0TBbmSEgadjUU29uAs58Jzz2AlVjvdpydY7StnephlMNs35yHwT         g2cmR7UJGVrROC7stJu4eqqJicM0c3l/afwXtDDR+DQtE7Hz85DQVtz7y8slODhh9QceX82Rrw/e          vDHE9IBuYQ/+LQD2TZl+w+ELzKV2kIZzf/rWwhjFurlr2GWhy7CpVfwrPANUHf0ups2VHLIdaNdz          RN9E9biDISzxxW4A1lTk0cKu9Iq44WVW+hY5EiwebSIZrOTkmAYcY3+iYlNT3dpjmE0Ub6uS/zkn         yQei2hQcuncA8BXUyXj93sGNL+N6m8E+dXg9yh/ta7Kw2WLFerC3OahmIwLq/qKbBiSRgfCqlDaA          d+VwkH7jtoJyDjO1wpfJHtIXtOECjsYbyUMfPmcvs71XlutHWnO5Jdfn5zKHSM6ckAn5qT8HUBxs         L+UaS6N/5q5weDXTvwbAyy6aFjssbX+QPhcHlBokCfrAz/Zn3fJG5o4wrijpxPAPV2XTZq/spOF4         nMxf/DG83qWlW4sVL23j+g3Vtyu/zen9i9hK747ZZM7nh7ufrwPg1DkPrJL8XCCoXVTj1Z6xZXJz          ZJzduoObJtOY1eTV12pOzE01aMNyqYHKqQrewtLbN1ZeFHTiukbt4eWbpUnIZ3PyrTvz8EhR6Wkx          MVQThjW/nOoy1mSWJurZV0yhciJjXrGuwT0ZipjCncah/o9dSDzn+hxKO9VKdEcFu8BwvbgPy9XI         WRRBRQYaO0s3P7ohDl22IRZlA10DfkEU4JFAqXsZb5d4U3RCMNGxhwY7373lk7AtedeowazItYIX         n7LV0Bx8RHQv2AUJMmWgzuWd/oslJwT9loNkBmOuRfr9h3YJ70Hxi40vmQGASjlFO0AigysCaYHq          UHOSaACXt9dDDgZlJXClyxBszo4tmGKJp
```

It looks like correct Base64 string but if you check it - it's not. Do you have any idea why is that ? Is it bitmap issue ,or what ? Any help, please ?

Comment: `I add, that bitmap is ok , cuz I can display it in ImageView without any problems.`. You should start decoding the base64 encoded string back to a bitmap again on Android side.

Comment: Save the received string to file on server side. How many bytes? And how many bytes send? Do some elementary debugging.

Comment: `What I want to do later is to sent this photo to server`. But how did you send the base64 string to the server now?

Comment: `Looks ok, right ? Well, it's not` Yes, it looks ok. And what is it that you received on server side that is not ok? Elaborate please. Start with amount of bytes sent and received.

Comment: I add issues like that. Was because I forgot to specify the character encoding (UTF-8 in my case) in the server call.

Answer (score 1):

use this method to `encode` the `bitmap` you want

```
  public static String enBitmap64(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        bitmap.recycle();
        byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(array, 0);
    }
```

and this method to decode the `string`

```
public static Bitmap deBitmap64(String string) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(string, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    return decodedByte;
}
```

However, before using `encode64` you need to know few things

- Encode and decode bitmaps needs to be done in `background` (NOT IN THE MAIN THREAD) it hangs the UI specially if the `bitmap` was large, use `Asynctask`, `Service` or `Runnable` **(`Asynctask` is best choice)**.
- It's not recommended to encode large images and upload it as string to server, encode and decode only in two cases.

**First**, if all you images are small.

**Second**, if you have large images and somewhere you app you display it as thumbnail For exp; In friends search of Facebook you see small images(thumbnail) you click it becomes large(original image). so there is small image and large image, when you are in friends search page you only request(download) the small image (low resolution) from the server no need to request(download) such large image(high resolution), but the two images are stored in the server. the small one could be saved as encoded but NOT the large one, large images is to be upload to server though `HttpClient`, `Volley` or `HttpURLConnection`.. there are more

Answer (score 1):

I have almost the same issue,

encoding and decoding were working perfectly on the java side.

But my Base64 string couldn't be decoded on the server side.
comparing different base64s helped me to see that my base64 break into lines so using following code helped to correct base64

```js
base64string.replace("\n", ""));
```